# How to populating RDF data from RDBMS-based system

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology, rule-engine, jena-rules

I am new to semantic-web and ontology. From few weeks ago I am start reading papers and online course about it. I have an idea to use ontology rule-based system  for extending the feature on my existing reminder system, as can be seen in the attached picture. I've read about Ontology, Rules (e.g. SPIN, SPARQL), Inference engine (e.g. Jena), RDF, RDFS, OWL etc. I think I've got the general idea about it.

System Architecture:
[image: System Architecture]

However, one thing that I still miss is: how to integrate this rule-based system into my current system. the current system data is stored in RDBMS (mysql) database. Every transaction data on the system has the possibility to be modified in later time after creation. Meanwhile, ontology-based system - AFAIK, rely on RDF data format. My thinking is, there should be a way to convert the trx data from RDBMS to RDF to be ready to use by the ontology system.

My question are:

1. Does my thinking correct?
2. What is best practise of this process?
3. When there is a modified data on the existing record (RDBMS), how to reflect it on the RDF?
4. In relation to #3, in case of not using RDBMS, how the ontology system manage their RDF data if there is an update of individual property? is that depend on the underlying triple-store database? Since I read that using TDB only able to insert or delete.

Comment: So, you should continue with reading and look for *"rdb2rdf"* - there are plenty of approaches, the most popular being `R2RML`. And obviously, you need 1) the DB 2) an ontology aka RDF schema and finally 3) the mapping from DB to RDF. R2RML is one approach among others to express and process those mappings.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you for your response. I think that is what I need. I just read few of the tools. I am wondering, how the ontology system manage the dynamic RDF data, if there is no RDBMS included? I just update my question, to reflect this, since it is still relevant with the overall questions.

Comment: What is an "ontology system" for you? And what means "dynamic data" for you"? The are basically 2 ways to use relational databases once you defined the mappings from the relational database schema to the RDF schema: 1) convert the data to RDF and load it to a native RDF triple store or 2) there is a SPARQL to SQL rewriter in the background. Clearly, in case 1), once the RDB data has been changed, you would have to rerun the conversion and reload the RDF data. In case 2) it doesn't matter, you're still querying the RDB under the hood

Comment: @AKSW ontology system in the case of the right part of my architecture. and dynamic data is the data that is possibly change (e.g. reminder data that is being updated in the later time if it is responded by the user). I was thinking of two options to create the rule-based system, integrating with the current system (RDBMS) or completely using RDF triple store without the RDBMS. that's why I dynamic data question came up. Your 2 cases clarified my questions well. In case #1, do you mean reloading all resources (RDF data)? or it can be only specific resources?

Comment: it can also be specific resources of your RDBMS, but it can become difficult to find the proper diff of the RDF data. I mean, changing some row in the databases means you have to remove the old corresponding RDF triples first, then insert the new RDF triples. As long as you are able to do this, it's indeed much more efficient than converting the data, delete the old data and loading the whole new data. don't forget, there is no "overwrite" of a value in RDF, it would just add a new RDF triple for the same propery, that's why you have to remove the old one first

Comment: Thanks @AKSW, I think I’ve got better understanding now. Btw, I am new here, how I can make it as accepted answer?